# How to convert unicode to MySQL PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

My site gets input and translates it to Unicode like this:

```
6;&#172;&#216;&#167;&#216;&#175; &#216;&#168;&#216;&#167;&#216;&#178;&#219;&#140;
```

and puts it into a database.

Can PHP code get this and translate it to UTF-8 text? And import it again in the database?

I know how to get data and how to put it to database but I just don't know how to convert this type of Unicode to normal text with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try explicitly adding content type at the top of your file as below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and then

```
$string = '6;&#172;&#216;&#167;&#216;&#175; &#216;&#168;&#216;&#167;&#216;&#178;&#219;&#140;';
echo html_entity_decode($string);
```

and before saving to database you need to

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`htmlentities_decode`](http://php.net/html-entity-decode) to get actual characters.

Comment: its output something like this: ا�Œجاد باز�Œ �ˆ �…ساب�‚ات در سا�Œت

Comment: Well, that means you have unconverted characters. Try [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8-encode).